# How to design a button from bottom of my Grid in Xamarin.forms

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms

I have a grid view and I want to add a button in bottom of my screen
I have used following code:

```
[![enter image description here][1]][1]
    <Grid>[![enter image description here][2]][2]
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="2*" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="88*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="12*"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
          <Grid Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" BackgroundColor="White">
          <Grid Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" BackgroundColor="White">
     <Grid Grid.Row="1" BackgroundColor="#f24245" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                <Button Text="Lookupjshgkdfjghkdjfghdkjfhgdlfkjghfk" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" TextColor="White" FontSize="Large" BackgroundColor="#f24245"/>
            </Grid>
               </Grid>


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vsEn9.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TazCg.png
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please Add **Grid.ColumnSpan="2"** Like,

```
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="2*" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="88*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="12*"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" BackgroundColor="White">
                <!--Place you code Here-->
            </Grid>
            <Grid Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" BackgroundColor="White">
                <!--Place you code Here-->
            </Grid>
            <Grid Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" BackgroundColor="#f24245" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                <Button Text="Lookupjshgkdfjghkdjfghdkjfhgdlfkjghfk" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" TextColor="White" FontSize="Large" BackgroundColor="#f24245"/>
            </Grid>
        </Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use VerticalOptions="End"
Example:

```
        <Grid Padding="20" RowSpacing="0">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="0.7*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="0.3*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <!-- row 0 -->
        <Image Grid.Row="0" Source="icon-76.png" WidthRequest="150" HeightRequest="150" />
        <!-- row 1 -->
        <StackLayout Grid.Row="2" VerticalOptions="End">
            <Button Margin="0,5,0,5" Text="Button at the bottom" BackgroundColor="#4a4acd" TextColor="White" FontAttributes="Bold" />
        </StackLayout>
    </Grid>
```

This will give you the following view:
[image]